# Transforming Cassini coordinates to UTM

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography, utm, land-survey

Why is it that when I transform certain Cassini coordinates to UTM, they give negative UTM coordinates, which should not be the case. Note that the equator passes through this particular area of interest. These are the coordinates Cassini in the order (E,N) The units are in feet.

```
244000, 2000
248000, 2000
248000, -2000
244000, -2000
```

Comment: If data in a northern hemisphere UTM zone crosses the Equator, it *should* produce negative coordinates.

Comment: But I thought UTM coordinates cannot be negative.